# Modx white screen for Resources and Chunks

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I tried to recreate a modx install by running setup and after creating the database, deleting it and importing an existing one. This seemed to work fine except I can't load Resources or Chunks (white screen). I can load Snippets and Templates just fine, and the rest of the manager seems to function. No output to the Error Log either. Anyone know what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Sean for your response. Luckily I was able to use Quick Update to view the Chunks, and recreated the site with a fresh modx DB. Not sure if this is an "answer" exactly, but there it is!

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache, both browser and modx - then make sure the webserver can read & write to the cache directory [ /core/cache/ ]
If no luck there - disable CSS & JS compression in your system settings.